# Socket io doesn't connect after calling disconnect function .i.e Connect -> Disconnect -> Connect won't work iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I am working on Chat engine using Socket io version 15.2.0,

When first time when I call socket.connect() it works properly, then if I call socket.disconnect() and then again try to call socket.connect() then socket fails to connect without any error or log. Then I have to kill the app and need to relaunch the app then socket connects without any issue.

following is my Shared class for Socket connect and disconnect

```
 class SocketHelper {

    static let shared = SocketHelper()
    var socket: SocketIOClient!

    let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: ApiUrls.socketUrl)!, config: [.log(true), .compress, .connectParams(["token": Globals.shared.session.accessToken]), .secure(true), .forceNew(true)])
    
    private init() {
        socket = self.manager.defaultSocket
    }
    
    func getSocketWithLazyConnect() -> SocketIOClient {
        if self.socket.status == .connected {
            return self.socket
        }
        
        self.socket.connect()
        
        return self.socket
    }
    
    func disconnect() {
        self.socket.disconnect()
    }
    
    func isConnected() -> Bool {
        return self.socket.status == .connected
    }
 }
```

Any help much appreciated...

Comment: if you can , I might suggest you to use `GCDWebServer`....it's much easier to use but if you want to continue with `Socket.IO` , I will get back to you after some research...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys but I figured out what I was doing wrong

I have one shared class named ChatEngine it handle all chat related socket events.

in that method while to disconnect from socket, I wrote a function switchOff

```
func switchOff() {
    socket?.off(Constants.SocketEvent.connect)
    SocketHelper.shared.disconnect()
}
```

as shown above I was calling off funtion for connect event and that's why after that when I called socket.connect, I didn't received any call back for that inside

```
self.socket?.on(clientEvent: .connect, callback: { (data, ack) in 

})
```

I just removed off function call from my switchOff function and now it's working fine. Now my switchOff function is like this

```
func switchOff() {
    SocketHelper.shared.disconnect()
}
```